# uploading Financial Account Role records, Hitting significant apex errors

Tags: apex, trigger, cpulimit, financial-services-cloud

We are loading roughly ~ Financial account role records for joint owners, but are seeing roughly ~50 % failure rate due to apex time out issues.

We have disabled our own custom triggers and have no other processes on the Financial Account Role object.

Could it be that out data is incorrect? and this is whats causing the time out issues?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest starting by reducing the batch size of the upload. CPU timeout errors can be difficult to track down but this is probably a good starting point.

Are you using data loader for this? If so, you can update the batch size by navigating to Settings > Batch Size Limit and setting it to a lower value. It defaults to 200, but I've had to go as low as 10 in certain scenarios where there are a lot of cross object updates or recursion happening. You can experiment with this number to try and find a happy medium where you get a good success rate but don't have to wait a million years for it to run.